# How to display sub nodes in different node groups separately?

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am new with xslt. I am converting an XML file to a flat file. But the sub nodes values are shown together under every node group. How can I show them separately?

XML:

```
<list>
    <group name="group1">
        <item value="item1" />
        <item value="item11" />
    </group>
    <group name="group2">
        <item value="item2" />
        <item value="item22" />
        <item value="item222" />
    </group>
</list>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//list1/group">
      <xsl:text>group name</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      <!--item -->
      <xsl:for-each select="//list1/group/item">
        <xsl:text>item value</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
    group name  group1
    item value item1
    item value item11
    item value item2
    item value item22
    item value item22
    group name  group2
    item value item1
    item value item11
    item value item2
    item value item22
    item value item22
```

Expected output:

```
    group name  group1
    item value item1
    item value item11
    group name  group2
    item value item2
    item value item22
    item value item222
```

Comment: @SirFartALot Please do not edit OP's code; you don't know what it looks like.

Comment: @michael.hor257k to achieve better readability it's neccessary to (re-)indent code correctly. XML/XSLT and a lot of programming languages are often unreadably indented in questions, so it's just legit to edit the question for readability. I don't get your point on not to edit indention on question's code...

Comment: @SirFartALot White space may be significant to the problem. As long as the problem has not been positively identified, editing the code can obfuscate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your posted code is here:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//list1/group/item">
```

This will always select all `item` nodes in the entire XML document, starting from the root node and ignoring the current context.

Earlier, when you did:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//list1/group">
```

you were put in the context of `group`. From here, to process the `item` elements that are children of the current `group`, you should do simply:

```
<xsl:for-each select="item">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael! I tried this before but it didn't work. Because I kept "//" in the select value, as <xsl:for-each select="//item">. It is working after removing them.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better off using the `xsl` matching capabilities instead of "`for-each`"

Possible solution (selects all `item`s and then outputs the parent's `name` and the `item`'s `value`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="//list/group/item">
    <xsl:text>group name: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="../@name"/><xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>item value: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@value" /><xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Following code check:-

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="group">
  <xsl:text>group name</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>

<xsl:text>item value</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="item/@value" />

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/?save=b5f3db91-b351-42fe-9a29-c4e006233517-xsltransformation#.XTBE9fIzaM8

Comment: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/?save=892bb95f-b9f6-45ba-bfb7-b38df4f16257-xsltransformation#.XTBJbfIzaM8

Comment: Thanks Ajeet! This is working if there is only one item in each group. But there are some more in the group. But it is working after replace template to for-each in the item level template.
e.g.
`code`
`
<list>
<group name="group1">
    <item value="item1" />
    <item value="item11" />
</group>
<group name="group2">
    <item value="item2" />
    <item value="item22" />
<item value="item222" />
</group>
</list>`